# ArgoCD apps of apps with local repo

Tags: argocd

I use the apps of apps approach with ArgoCD, and my child apps look like this:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
...
spec:
...
  source:
    path: helm-charts/chart/version
    repoURL: 'git@path/to/git/repo.git'
    targetRevision: HEAD
```

There are roughly 80 child apps below the root app, and each child is repeating the repoURL `git@path/to/git/repo.git`. Can I replace this by a relative path respective of the parent application which is also committed to the same git repo?